# Raychaudhuri equation and expansion scalar for constant $a(t)$ FLRW metric

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, space-expansion

On the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raychaudhuri_equation) for the Raychaudhuri equation, the expansion scalar $\theta$ is described as the rate of change of volume of a ball of matter with respect to the time of a central, comoving observer.

Considering an FLRW metric in Cartesian coordinates with simply $a(t)=t$, $\theta$ is negative, but I was always puzzled as to why, since the FLRW universe is expanding. Does it have something to do with the comoving observer thing?

Comment: $a(t)=t$ is not “constant $a(t)$”.

Comment: Oh, sorry, forget about the constant part.